# Access to UITextField in CellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

i´m adding a UITextField on a Cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


myLoc = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, 250, 40)];
myLoc.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
myLoc.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myLoc.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myLoc.placeholder = @"Enter Location";
myLoc.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
myLoc.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
myLoc.tag = indexPath.row;
myLoc.delegate = self;
[myLoc setEnabled:YES];
[cell addSubview:myLoc];

return cell;
}
```

and in the textFieldShouldReturn i would write the text from the textfield in a mutable array, and store in nsuserdefaults.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[myLoc resignFirstResponder];

[locationArray addObject:textField.text];
locName = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[locName setObject:locationArray forKey:@"textName"];
[locName synchronize];

NSLog(@"Done pressed %@",myLoc.text);

return YES;
```

}

...but the myLoc.text is always null
any ideas for me?

Answer (score 2):

In the delegate method, don't use `myLoc` to reference the textField, but use the actual `textField` pointer provided as parameter of the function. This one should actually point to the correct textfield and thus textField.text should have the correct value.

On a side note: Where do you define `myLoc`? It looks like you're trying to set a property on your viewcontroller. This way you'll always overwrite the property. For this you don't need a property at all, so just define `myLoc` locally in the function scope like `UILabel *myLoc`

Answer (score 1):

You're better off creating your own custom UITableViewCell.  You can see how to create one here: 
[tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

Trying to tack on to the existing UITableViewCell is difficult at best and impossible at worst.  You're better off with custom cells.

Comment: Owen is right. Have a subclass also leads to cleaner code and to better maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Your text should never be NULL, since its an NSString. Are you sure you're talking about the text from the text field?

What outputs when you add NSLog(@%"@", textField.text); to your shouldReturn method?

Are you sure that you have typed in the text field? Also, even without typing, you should be getting @"" instead of nil.

Comment: problem solved with myLoc = textField in textFieldShouldReturn

Comment: That shouldn't do anything, unless if you were calling the text property of myLoc and not the textField instance given in the delegate method. Is that what you were doing?